# What did Smith mean when he said this?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

When Neo, the Keymaker and Morpheus are cut off by Smith before they reach the door they want, Neo asks Smith what he wants. Smith then says

> Oh, you haven't you figured that out? still using all the muscles except the one that matters. I want exactly what you want, I want everything.

He goes on to repeat this in Revolutions when he is Bane.

What does he mean when he says Neo wants everything? Neo doesn't want everything. Neo wants peace. I don't think he wants fame. Did Smith have a meaningful thing behind this or was he just being smart.

Comment: Nitpick: [Bane was *him*.](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64609/if-agent-smith-is-just-an-ai-program-then-how-could-he-end-up-in-the-real-world#comment103178_64609)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that Agent Smith is the one who said this, not Neo.  Not everything that a given character says is necessarily the absolute truth.  Agent Smith is speaking from his own perspective, and of his own opinion, which is not necessarily the same as Neo's.  Agent Smith may well believe this is the truth, but other people (in particular, Neo and the "good guys") may not agree.

At this point in the series, Neo is well on his way to becoming The One - an all-powerful (or at least *way more powerful than usual*) being who can bend the Matrix to his whim.  Also, let's not forget what Neo did to Agent Smith at the end of the first movie - he possessed Smith in a manner similar to how the Agents possess regular people, and then "dispersed" him.  (I won't say killed, because obviously Smith came back later.)

From Smith's perspective, this uppity human is making a power-play.  He's gaining more power than any human ought to have over the Matrix.  To make matters worse, Smith can't even begin to understand *how a human got this powerful.*  To Smith, it certainly seems like Neo "wants everything."  That's why he says what he says.  It may seem true *to him,* but of course we, the audience, know better.

Comment: Wow, really cool response! So, Smith is (to coin a phrase) somewhat "butthurt"  about Neos extreme power. Funny, I always found Smith to remind me of the Stalker in Cape Fear in some way.

Comment: Sometimes you know the answer but having another person write it down makes it seem legit to an extent.

Comment: I suppose you also have to think that Agent Smith thinks logically and to his point of view Neo does look like he wants everything since he has powers way beyond any human.

Comment: So Agent Smith was correct, *from a certain point of view*.

Comment: True altruism doesn't exist IMO. Nothing could be closer to the ultimate goal of a white hat hacker than giving everyone else their own 'everything'.